# Opening image in a new window and then opening a new one once they close it

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to make user friendly step by step instructions on how to do a certain process however I am having trouble with:

1. Opening photos(.pnb, .jpeg, etc...)
2. Having it appear in a msgbox type form instead of the photo file being opened.
3. After that once they close the a new msg box will appear afterword with a new photo.

I have tried the Application.FollowHyperlink and it returns Run Time Error:438 "Object doesn't support this property or method and have tried the shell command with Error: 5 Invalid Procedure call or Argument.

Any help would be appreciated let me know if you need any more information about the problem

Comment: Use a userform.

Comment: Wouldn't it be more user friendly if they do not have to close the image but use a next and previous button to toggle between images? :)

Comment: Yes it would @Siddharth Rout but that seems like I would have to ask another question about doing that exact thing because I am not sure how to do that either

Comment: How exactly would you use a userform that comment doesn't help me much @BigBen

Comment: There's not enough detail in your question to help you ... where are these images stored? A `MsgBox`  can't show an image, but a userform can.

Comment: Use an Image control in the userform and then show the image there :)

Comment: https://analysistabs.com/vba-code/excel-userform/image/

Comment: @BigBen The images are stored in just the pictures folder I found some tutorials online about them and I think I have the hang of it now Thank you for suggesting it.

Comment: @SiddharthRout Thank you I think I figured it out

Answer (score 0):

Figured out to use userforms to insert pictures and hide tabs on the multipage whenever I click the command button.

Comment: No this is not what I meant. You can use one image control and simply click on the Next/Previous button to load the image using `LoadPicture()` in the image control. You can store all the image paths in an array.

Comment: Ohhh ok I appreciate your help. @SiddharthRout